# Java not being detected with Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox, java, java-applet

I am on Windows 7 64-bit using Firefox 7 and JDK 7. Firefox is not able to detect the Java plugin and I am not able to run java plugins.

Comment: Is javascript enabled in Firefox content options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you installed the 64-bit Java plugin but since Firefox is likely 32-bit, you actually need the 32-bit Java plugin instead?

Comment: This is the Firefox user-agent string: 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0" I guess its 64-bit.

Comment: Installing 32-bit JDK worked.

Comment: For future reference, you probably didn't need the entire JDK, just the JRE.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check that the Java plugin is installed on firefox ?

EDIT : you can see [here](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Using%20the%20Java%20plugin%20with%20Firefox)

**Enabling Java**

If Java is not working, make sure that the Java plugin is enabled in the Add-ons window Manager tab:

At the top of the Firefox window, click on the Firefox button (Tools menu in Windows XP), and then click Add-onsOn the menu bar, click on the Tools menu, and then click Add-onsAt the top of the Firefox window, click on the Tools menu, and then click Add-ons. The Add-ons Manager tab will openAt the top of the Firefox window, click on the Tools menu, and select Add-onsOn the menu bar, click on the Tools menu, and select Add-onsAt the top of the Firefox window, click on the Tools menu, and select Add-ons. The Add-ons window will open.

In the Add-ons Manager tabwindow, select the Plugins panel.

Click on the Java (TM) Platform pluginJava Embedding Plug-InJava Plug-in 2 for NPAPI Browsers (Mac OS 10.5 & 10.6) or Java Applet Plug-in (Mac OS 10.7)Java plugin to select it.

Click on the Enable button (if the button says Disable, Java is already enabled).

Note: You only need to enable the "Java(TM) Platform" plugin, if it is disabled. The "Java Deployment Toolkit" plugin is used by Java developers to detect your Java version and to deploy their Java applications and does not need to be enabled for Java to work.

Comment: Yes, its not showing up in the plugins list.

Comment: So add the java plugin since the official Java website. It will be make you able to use java with your browser